# Apache - conditional rewrite to authenticate and anonymous version of an webapp

Tags: apache

I need to create a link in my webpage like this

https://myapp.com

If the client clicks in the link and is authenticated the response will be something like https://myapp.com/approot but if the user is not authenticated the response will be https://myapp.com/login.html.
In the later case when the user is not authenticated I want to rewrite the response to send user to an anonymous version of the app, eg https://appanom.com

1) Can I do this with Apache 2.4?
2) It's is a good practice? Or there is a better way to implement this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this and see if this helps. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_form.html

Comment: I think this will not work, auth is already handled by another app.